# Object Oriented Library Management System

Tags: c++, beginner, object-oriented, design-patterns

Library management system is a object oriented program that takes care of the basic housekeeping of a library.
This is the third part of a series. The first iteration of the project is found [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/250668/library-management-system-with-oop) and the second iteration is also found [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/250769/library-management-system-oop-with-c-part2-of-a-series)

The major actors are the Librarian, Member, and the System.

#### Major Concern

I made member and Librarian friends of the system class and also composed the system class with Librarian and Member. I felt "System is composed of a Librarian and members" sounds better than "System is a friend of a Librarian and members". Does this follow the common design patterns?

In my previous post, I wasn't cleared well enough on why a std::vector should be preferable than std::list in this situation due to the fact that the system would perform insertion frequently. Would std::vector be more scalable and versatile whilst taking speed and efficiency into consideration?

Any other observation on potential pitfalls, traps and common bad practice can be pointed out.

**Date.hh**

```
#ifndef DATE_HH
#define DATE_HH

class Date {
    friend std::ostream &operator<<( std::ostream &, const Date & );
     private:
        /* data-members */
        unsigned month = 1;
        unsigned day = 1;
        unsigned year = 1970;

        /* utility functions */
        bool validateDate( unsigned m, unsigned d = 1, unsigned y = 1970 );
        bool checkDay( unsigned m, unsigned d, unsigned y ) const;
        bool isLeapYear( unsigned y ) const { return ( y % 400 == 0 ) || ( y % 4 == 0 && y % 100 != 0 ); }
    public:
        static constexpr unsigned int monthsPerYear = 12;

        /* ctors */
        Date() = default;
        Date( unsigned m, unsigned d, unsigned y );
        Date( unsigned m );
        Date( unsigned m, unsigned d );
        
        /* copy operations */
        Date( const Date &d ) = default;
        Date &operator=( const Date &d ) = default;

        /* equality test operations */
        bool operator==( const Date &d ) const;
        bool operator!=( const Date &d ) const { return !( *this ==  d ); }

        /* method-functions */
        void setDate( unsigned m = 1, unsigned d = 1, unsigned y = 1970 );
        unsigned  getMonth() const;
        unsigned getDay() const;
        unsigned  getYear() const;       
        void nextDay();
        const std::string toString() const;

        // dtor
        ~Date(){};
};

#endif
```

**Date.cc**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <array>
#include "../headers/Date.hh"

Date::Date( unsigned m, unsigned d, unsigned y ) { 
    if ( validateDate(m, d, y ) ) {
        month = m; day = d; year = y;
    }
}

Date::Date( unsigned m ) {
    if( validateDate( m ) )
        month = m;
}

Date::Date( unsigned m, unsigned d ) {
    if ( validateDate( m, d ) ) {
        month = m; day = d;
    }
}

void Date::setDate( unsigned m, unsigned d, unsigned y ) {
    if ( validateDate( m, d, y ) ) {
        month = m; day = d; year = y;
    }
}

void Date::nextDay() {
    day += 1;
    try {
        checkDay( month, day, year );
    } catch ( std::invalid_argument &e ) {
        month += 1;
        day = 1;
    }
    if ( month % 12 == 0 ) {
        year += 1;
        month = 1;
    }
}
bool Date::operator==( const Date &d ) const {
    if( month != d.month ) return false;
    if ( day != d.day ) return false;
    if ( year != d.year ) return false;

    return true;
}

std::ostream &operator<<( std::ostream &os, const Date &d ) {
    os << d.month << "/" << d.day << "/" << d.year;

    return os;
} 

// utility function
bool Date::validateDate( unsigned m, unsigned d, unsigned y ) {
    // validate month
    if ( m < 1 || m >= 13 )
        throw std::invalid_argument( "Month must be between 1-12" );

    // validate day
    if ( checkDay( m, d, y ) == false )
        throw std::invalid_argument( "Invalid day for current month and year" );
    
    // validate year
    if ( y < 1970 )
        throw std::invalid_argument( "year must be greater than 1969" );
    
    return true;
}

 const std::string Date::toString() const {
     return std::to_string(month) + "/" + std::to_string(day) + "/" + std::to_string(year);
 }

bool Date::checkDay( unsigned testMonth, unsigned testDay, unsigned testYear ) const {
    static const std::array < unsigned, monthsPerYear + 1 > daysPerMonth = { 0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,32,30,31};

    if ( testDay > 0 && testDay <= daysPerMonth[ testMonth ] )
        return true;
    
    if ( testMonth == 2 && testDay == 29 && isLeapYear( testYear ) ) 
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

**BookItem.hh**

```
#ifndef BOOKITEM_HH
#define BOOKITEM_HH

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include "Date.hh"

enum class BookStatus : unsigned { RESERVED, AVAILABLE, UNAVAILABLE, REFERENCE, LOANED, NONE };
enum class BookType : unsigned { HARDCOVER, MAGAZINE, NEWSLETTER, AUDIO, JOURNAL, SOFTCOPY };

class BookItem {
    friend std::ostream &operator<<( std::ostream &, const BookItem & );

    private:
        /* data-members */
        std::string title;
        std::string author;
        std::string category;
        Date pubDate;
        std::string isbn;
        BookStatus status;
        BookType type;

        /* user connected to this book */
        std::string bookcurrentUser;

    public:
        /* ctors */
        BookItem() = default;
        BookItem( const std::string &title, const std::string &author, const std::string &cat, const Date &pubDate, \
                const std::string &isbn, const BookType type,  const BookStatus status = BookStatus::AVAILABLE ); 

        bool operator==( const BookItem &bookItem ) const;
        bool operator!=( const BookItem &bookItem ) const { return !( *this == bookItem); };

        /* method-functions */
        void setStatus( BookStatus s ) { status = s; };
        void setType( BookType t ) { type = t;};
        void setCategory( const std::string &c ) { category = c; }
        void setBookCurrentUser( std::string userName ) { bookcurrentUser = userName; }
        std::string_view getBookCurrentUser() const { return bookcurrentUser; }
        std::string_view getStatus() const;
        std::string_view getType() const;
        std::string_view getTitle() const { return title; }
        std::string_view getAuthor() const { return author; }
        std::string_view getCategory() const { return category; };
        std::string_view getIsbn() const { return isbn; }
        Date &getPubDate() { return pubDate; }
        void printPubDate() const { std::cout << pubDate; } 
        const BookStatus getStatusByEnum() const { return status; }
        const BookType getTypeByEnum() const { return type; }

        // dtor
        ~BookItem() = default;
};
#endif
```

**BookItem.cc**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "../headers/BookItem.hh"

BookItem::BookItem( const std::string &t, const std::string &a, const std::string &c, const Date &d, \
                const std::string &i, const BookType ty, const BookStatus s ) {
                    title = t, author = a, category = c, pubDate = d, isbn = i;
                    setStatus( s );
                    setType( ty );
}

bool BookItem::operator==( const BookItem &bookItem ) const {
    if ( title != bookItem.title ) return false;
    if ( author != bookItem.author ) return false;
    if ( category != bookItem.category ) return false;
    if ( pubDate != bookItem.pubDate ) return false;
    if ( isbn != bookItem.isbn ) return false;
    if ( status != bookItem.status ) return false;
    if ( type != bookItem.type ) return false;

    return true;
}

std::string_view BookItem::getStatus() const { 
    switch( status ) {
        case BookStatus::AVAILABLE:
            return "AVAILABLE";
        case BookStatus::REFERENCE:
            return "REFERENCE";
        case BookStatus::UNAVAILABLE:
            return "UNAVAILABLE";
        case BookStatus::LOANED:
            return "LOANED";
        case BookStatus::RESERVED:
            return "RESERVED";
        default:
            return "NONE";
    }
} 

std::string_view BookItem::getType() const {
    switch( type ) {
        case BookType::AUDIO:
            return "AUDIO";
        case BookType::HARDCOVER:
            return "HARDCOVER";
        case BookType::JOURNAL:
            return "JOURNAL";
        case BookType::MAGAZINE:
            return "MAGAZINE";
        case BookType::NEWSLETTER:
            return "NEWSLETTER";
        case BookType::SOFTCOPY:
            return "SOFTCOPY";
        default:
            return "NONE";
    }
}

std::ostream &operator<<( std::ostream &os, const BookItem &b ) {
        os << "\nName of book: " << b.getTitle();
        os << "\nAuthor of book: " << b.getAuthor();
        os << "\nBook category: " << b.getCategory();
        os << "\nPublication date: " << b.pubDate;
        os << "\nISBN number: " << b.getIsbn();
        os << "\nStatus of book: " << b.getStatus();
        os << "\nType of book: " << b.getType();
        return os;
}
```

**Librarian.hh**

```
#ifndef LIBRARIAN_HH
#define LIBRARIAN_HH

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "BookItem.hh"

class System;

class Librarian {
    public:
        /* data-members */
        std::string name;
        Date dateOfHire;

        /* ctors */
        Librarian() = default;
        Librarian( const std::string &name, const Date &dateOfHire );

        // basic method-function
        void printDateOfHire() const { std::cout << dateOfHire; }

        /* core functionalities */
        void addBook( System &sys, const BookItem &isbn );
        void removeBook( System &sys, const std::string &isbn );
        void auditLibrary( const System &sys ) const;

        // dtor
        ~Librarian(){}
};

#endif
```

**Librarian.cc**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "../headers/System.hh"
#include "../headers/Librarian.hh"

Librarian::Librarian( const std::string &n, const Date &d ) {
    name = n;
    dateOfHire = d;
}

void Librarian::addBook(System &sys, const BookItem &book ) { 
    if ( sys.books.empty() ) {
        sys.books.push_front( book );
        return;
    }
    for ( auto bptr = sys.books.cbegin(); bptr != sys.books.cend(); ++bptr ) {
        if( book.getTitle() <= bptr->getTitle() ) {
            sys.books.insert(bptr, book);
            return;
        }
    }
    sys.books.push_back( book );
}

void Librarian::removeBook( System &sys, const std::string &isbn ) {
    BookItem book = sys.getBook( isbn );
    for ( auto bptr = sys.books.cbegin(); bptr != sys.books.cend(); ++bptr ) {
        if ( book.getIsbn() == bptr->getIsbn() ) {
            sys.books.remove(book);
            std::cout << "Deleted { " << book.getAuthor() << " : " << book.getTitle() << " } \n";
            return;
        }
    }
    throw std::invalid_argument("Book not found");
}

void Librarian::auditLibrary( const System &sys ) const {
    std::cout << "\nName of Library: " << sys.libraryName << ", Date created " << sys.dateCreated;
    std::cout << "\nLibrarian: " << name << ", Date of hire: " << dateOfHire;
    std::cout << "\n\nBooks: ";
    for ( auto bptr = sys.books.cbegin(); bptr != sys.books.cend(); ++bptr ) {
        std::cout << *bptr << "\n";
        std::cout << "This book is linked to: " 
                << ( ( bptr->getBookCurrentUser() == "" ) ? "None" : bptr->getBookCurrentUser() ) << "\n"; 
    }
    std::cout << "\n\nMembers: ";
    for ( auto mPtr = sys.members.cbegin(); mPtr != sys.members.cend(); ++mPtr ) {
        std::cout << *mPtr << "\n";
    }
}
```

**Member.hh**

```
#ifndef MEMBER_HH
#define MEMBER_HH

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Date.hh"
#include "BookItem.hh"

class System;

class Member {
    friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream&os, const Member &m );

    private:
        /* data-member */
        std::string libraryNumber;
        Date dateRegisted;
        std::vector<BookItem> checkedOutBooks;

    public:
        /* data-member */
        std::string name;
        char sex;
        /* ctors */
        Member() = default;
        Member( const std::string &n, const char s, Date d ) : dateRegisted( d ), name( n ), sex( s ) {}
        
        /* method-functions */
        std::string getLibraryNumber() const { return libraryNumber; }
        void setLibraryNumber( const std::string &lNum ) { libraryNumber = lNum; };
        void checkOut( System &sys, const std::string &isbn );
        void returnBook( System &sys, const std::string &isbn );
        bool operator==( const Member &m );
        bool operator!=( const Member &m ) { return !( *this == m ); }

        // dtor
        ~Member() = default;
};

#endif
```

**System.cc**

```
#ifndef SYSTEM_HH
#define SYSTEM_HH

#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include "Date.hh"
#include "BookItem.hh"
#include "Librarian.hh"
#include "Member.hh"

class System {
    friend class Librarian;
    friend class Member;

    private:
        /* data-members */
        std::list<BookItem> books{};
        std::vector<Member> members{};
        Librarian librarian;
        Member member;

    public:
        /* ctors */
        System() = default;
        System( const std::string &name, Date &date ) : libraryName( name ), dateCreated( date ) {};

        /* method-functions */
        const std::string generateLibraryNumber() const;
        void addMember( Member &m ) { members.push_back( m ); };
        void deleteMember( Member &m );
        void displayMembers();
        BookItem getBook( const std::string &isbn ) const;
        void viewBook( const std::string isbn ) const;
        void placeOnReserve( const std::string, const std::string &isbn );
        void displayAllBooks() const;

        /* data-members */
        std::string libraryName;
        Date dateCreated;
    
        
        /* search functionalities */
        std::list<BookItem> queryByTitle( const std::string &t ) const;
        std::list<BookItem> queryByAuthor( const std::string &a ) const;
        std::list<BookItem> queryByPubDate( const Date &d );
        std::list<BookItem> queryByStatus( const BookStatus &s ) const;
        std::list<BookItem> queryByType( const BookType &ty ) const;

        // dtor
        ~System() = default;
};

#endif
```

**System.cc**

````
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include "../headers/System.hh"

std::list<BookItem> System::queryByTitle( const std::string &t ) const {
    std::list<BookItem> queryList;
    for ( auto bPtr = books.cbegin(); bPtr != books.cend(); ++bPtr ) {
        if ( bPtr->getTitle().find(t) != std::string::npos )
           queryList.push_back( *bPtr );
    }
    return queryList;
}

std::list<BookItem> System::queryByAuthor( const std::string &a ) const {
    std::list<BookItem> queryList;
     for ( auto bPtr = books.cbegin(); bPtr != books.cend(); ++bPtr ) {
        if ( bPtr->getAuthor().find(a) != std::string::npos )
           queryList.push_back( *bPtr );
    }
    return queryList;
}
std::list<BookItem> System::queryByPubDate( const Date &d ) {
    std::list<BookItem> queryList;
    for ( auto bPtr = books.begin(); bPtr != books.cend(); ++bPtr ) {
        if ( bPtr->getPubDate().toString().find(d.toString()) != std::string::npos )
           queryList.push_back( *bPtr );
    }
    return queryList;
}
std::list<BookItem> System::queryByStatus( const BookStatus &s ) const {
    std::list<BookItem> queryList;
    for ( auto bPtr = books.begin(); bPtr != books.cend(); ++bPtr ) {
        if ( bPtr->getStatusByEnum() == s )
           queryList.push_back( *bPtr );
    }
    return queryList;
}
std::list<BookItem> System::queryByType( const BookType &ty ) const {
     std::list<BookItem> queryList;
    for ( auto bPtr = books.begin(); bPtr != books.cend(); ++bPtr ) {
        if ( bPtr->getTypeByEnum() == ty )
           queryList.push_back( *bPtr );
    }
    return queryList;
}

void System::placeOnReserve( const std::string name, const std::string &isbn )  {
    for ( auto bPtr = books.begin(); bPtr != books.end(); ++bPtr ) {
        if ( bPtr->getIsbn() == isbn ) {
            bPtr->setStatus( BookStatus::RESERVED );
            bPtr->setBookCurrentUser( name );
        }
    }
}

BookItem System::getBook( const std::string &isbn ) const {
    for ( auto bPtr = books.cbegin(); bPtr != books.cend(); ++bPtr ) {
        if ( bPtr->getIsbn() == isbn )
            return *bPtr;
    }
    throw std::invalid_argument("Book is not available at the library");
}

void System::viewBook( const std::string isbn ) const {
    std::cout << getBook( isbn );    
}

const std::string System::generateLibraryNumber() const {
    static std::string Codes[10]{"XGS", "QWT", "OPI", "NMK", "DXF", "PXG", "OPI", "QPU", "IKL", "XYX" };
    static std::set< unsigned, std::greater<unsigned> > idSet;
    unsigned id;
    bool unique = false;
    unsigned index = 0 + rand() % 9;
    std::string code = Codes[ index ];
    while ( unique == false ) {
        id = 10000000 + rand() % 9999999;
        auto ret = idSet.emplace(id);
        if ( !ret.second ) {
            std::cout << "unique failed";
            unique = false;
            continue;
        }
        else 
            unique = true;
    }
    return code + std::to_string( id );
}

void System::deleteMember( Member &m ) {
    for ( auto mPtr = members.begin(); mPtr != members.end(); ++mPtr ) {
        if ( *mPtr == m ) {
            members.erase( mPtr );
            std::cout << "Deleted member: { Name: " << m.name << ", Library Number: " << m.getLibraryNumber() << 
            " }\n";
            return;
        }
    }
    throw std::invalid_argument("No such member found");
}

void System::displayMembers() {
    std::cout << "Members of Library: ( count : " << members.size() << " ) " << "\n";
    for ( auto mPtr = members.cbegin(); mPtr != members.cend(); ++mPtr ) {
        std::cout << *mPtr;
    }
}
void System::displayAllBooks() const {
    for ( auto bPtr = books.begin(); bPtr != books.end(); ++bPtr ) {
        std::cout << *bPtr <<  "\n\n";
    }
}
```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`Date`:**

- `Date.hh` is missing some includes (`<iostream>`, `<string>`).
- Don't supply a default constructor. It doesn't make sense to have a default date.
- Don't supply one- and two-argument constructors. Specifying a month and date in 1970 is unlikely to be very common.
- We should support years before 1970. There were books back then!
- `year` should be a signed number (even if that capability is unlikely to be used).
- `day` and `month` can be smaller types (e.g. `std::uint8_t`).
- `setDate()` is unnecessary, since we have the constructor and assignment.
- One would expect a function called `nextDay()` to return a copy, rather than modifying the `Date` instance (c.f. standard library iterators `next` and `advance`).
- If the destructor does nothing, we can omit it.
- `validateDate` can never return `false`, so it should have a `void` return value (and perhaps be called `throwIfInvalid` or something similar).
- Member functions that don't need access to a class instance's member variables (`validateDate` etc.) can be made `static`.
- I'd suggest printing dates as "yyyy-mm-dd" (or printing the month by name). Putting the day in the middle is highly illogical.
- If you have C++20, use `std::chrono::year_month_day` instead!

---

**`BookItem`:**

- We should use the constructor initializer list to initialize member variables.
- Again, we don't want a default constructor.
- We don't need to specify a destructor.
- Note that libraries often have several copies of the same book. When a book has an ISBN (mainstream publications after 1970), we don't need to duplicate the book data (title, author, etc.) for every copy of the book in the library. Perhaps we should move the book data into a separate class, and have a `std::variant<ISBN, BookData>` in `BookItem`? (But maybe that's going too far for this implementation).
- We should add a unique identifier for each item the library holds.

---

**`Librarian`:**

- `addBook` and `removeBook` should not be part of this class. They modify the `System` class internals, and should be part of the `System` class. `auditLibrary` should be moved there too.
- The default constructor shouldn't exist. The destructor doesn't need to exist.
- I don't think this class needs to exist at all for the current library functionality.

---

**`Member`:**

- Default constructor bad. Destructor unnecessary.
- We don't really want to store `BookItem`s here by value. We just need to store an ID for each item they have checked out.
- `checkOut` and `returnBook` shouldn't be here, they should be part of `System`.

---

**`System`:**

- Shouldn't have `friend`s.
- Should perhaps be called `Library`.
- Don't  worry about speed unless it actually becomes a problem. There's probably no point in even storing books by title (we're as likely to want to search by author or category or publication date or...).
- (Note that the title search doesn't take into account that the list is sorted by title!)
- `std::list` has few valid uses. It only becomes faster than `std::vector` for inserting and removing many (hundreds of thousands) of items from the *middle* of the list. `std::vector` would be fine here.
- Use range-based for loops where appropriate: `for (auto const& i: books) { ... }`.
- Note that the `<algorithm>` header supplies various functions to find and copy things.

Answer (score 2):

I've read answer by @user673679 and just want address a few issues.

I strongly disagree with disabling default constructors in classes like `Member/Date/BookItem`. If class has no default constructor then using it with `std::vector`, `std::map` and other template containers becomes very awkward in general. So it is a bad advise.

Instead you should make default constructed classes such as these be clearly uninitialized and add functions/methods that test it.

Another note: I want to expand upon `std::vector` vs `std::list`. `std::list` is a very slow container and unsuitable for most purposes. It requires a new allocation for each element and to find a middle element one needs to traverse half the list. So using `std::list` is almost a sacrilege. There a few rare cases where list could be beneficial but definitely not in this code.

Use `std::vector` instead. You'll need to eventually figure out how to properly manage memory and lookup for searching but use `std::vector` for storing the base classes. For instance, erasing a single element isn't worth rearranging the whole vector. Instead, just keep count of number of empty locations and if the number surpasses half the total size then rearrange it.

You still lack move constructor and move assignment for `BookItem`. Having it will improve performance of classes like `std::vector` that hold the book items.

Comment: I have no idea about move constructor, Am currently learning with c++ primer and I haven't yet gotten to the chapter were move constructors are discussed, I just wrote the program with my current knowledge.

Comment: Please elaborate on "Instead you should make default constructed classes such as these be clearly uninitialized and add functions/methods that test it."

Comment: There sometimes are legitimate reasons for disabling default constructors, although here I don't think there is an issue to have default constructors indeed.

Comment: @G.Sliepen there are legitimate reasons to disable various constructors including default ones. But the ones listed weren't such.

Comment: @theProgrammer e.g. you can by default instantiate the data with invalid day/month or simply have a boolean that states whether the class was instantiated. You may or may not differentiate the cases "invalid date" and "non initialized date" - it is up to your choice of design. Though, I believe the two cases are quite different and should be treated differently. Alternatively, you can utilize `std::optional`.

Comment: This are way above my level right now, I guess I would just stick to having no default constructors